# Android Exception No command output when running: 'am start <application/application>

Tags: android, exception

I am getting this when trying to run a Android 1.5 app in the emulator from Eclipse. Any ideas what this is, the Android documentation is somewhat sparse to say the least. My web searches have proven fruitless and i am on the verge of dumping the whole thing...

Any ideas
Rick

> eclipse.buildId=unknown
>   java.version=1.6.0_22 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader
>   constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86,
>   WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework
>   arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws
>   win32 -arch x86 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> Error Fri Nov 19 08:02:15 EST 2010 No
>   command output when running: 'am start
>   -n package -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c
>   android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on
>   device emulator-5554
>
> com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:277)
>   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:861)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:399)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:834)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:90)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:64)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)